# C Project - How to manage a feature list?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have multiple features that can be enabled or disabled at the build time in a project.

The current implementation uses declarations such as `#define FEATURE_FOO`. Whenever I need to do something related to a particular feature, I use a pre-processor directive such as `#ifdef`.

The features definitions are stored inside a global header file.

This approach have two drawbacks:

1. It requires to `#include` this global header in every file, before any other header.
2. I cannot easily disable a C file:

This is not very good:

```
// file: foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "main_header.h"
#ifdef FEATURE_FOO
...
#endif
```

Because I prefer this:

```
// file: foo.c
#ifdef FEATURE_FOO

#include <stdio.h>
...
#endif
```

So, another approach to this problem is to declare all my features at the build time:

```
gcc -DFEATURE_FOO -c %< -o %@
```

What I don't like here is that I manually need to pass each feature to my compiler.

An acceptable workaround would be to read a `features.list` file that contains all the features. In my Makefile I will have:

```
DEFINES=$(shell perl -ne 'print "-DFEATURE_$1 " if /(\w+)/' features.list)

%o: %c
    gcc $(DEFINES) -c %< -o $@
```

What better alternative can I find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use gcc's option `-include myheader.h`.

It adds the content of `myheader.h` to the very beginning of the current translation unit's source.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a GNU make based build process for most of my projects and although it wasn't about features so far, I used techniques that could help you here, too.

First, the idea to have a configuration file is very good, but why not just have it in `make` syntax and `include` it?

I use something like this

```
# default configuration
CC := gcc
DEBUG := 0
GCC32 := 0
USELTO := 1

# read local configuration
-include defaults.mk
```

You could use this for having a list of features, e.g. in your `defaults.mk`

```
FEATURES := foo bar baz
```

and then do something like

```
FEATUREDEFINES := $(addprefix -DFEATURE_, $(FEATURES))
```

---

There's a lot more *black magic* possible with GNU make when you use the `$(eval ...)` function -- this might be a good alternative for completely excluding a source file from compilation depending on your settings. I use this for platform-specific implementations. For example I have this included Makefile for building a binary:

```
P:= src
T:= csnake

csnake_SOURCES:= csnake.c utils.c game.c board.c snake.c food.c screen.c
csnake_PLATFORMSOURCES:= ticker.c
csnake_LDFLAGS:= -lm
csnake_posix_LDFLAGS:= -lcurses
csnake_dos_LDFLAGS:= -Wl,-Bstatic -lpdcurses
csnake_win32_LDFLAGS:= -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lpdcurses \
    -Wl,-Bdynamic -lwinmm
csnake_win32_RES:= res$(PSEP)csnake.rc

$(eval $(BINRULES))
```

My `P` is the current relative path in the source tree, `T` is the target to build and `PSEP` is just a helper variable containing `/` or `\` in order to be compatible with windows. The rest should be quite self-explanatory -- for `$(T)_PLATFORMSOURCES`, `$(BINRULES)` looks in the relative path `platform/$(PLATFORM)/`. It works like this:

```
define BINRULES
BINARIES += $$(BINDIR)$$(PSEP)$(T)$$(EXE)

$(T)_SOURCES_FULL := $$(addprefix $(P)$$(PSEP),$$($(T)_SOURCES))
ifneq ($$(strip $$($(T)_PLATFORMSOURCES)),)
$(T)_SOURCES_FULL += $$(addprefix \
    $(P)$$(PSEP)platform$$(PSEP)$$(PLATFORM)$$(PSEP), \
    $$($(T)_PLATFORMSOURCES))
endif

[...] (... further rules ... )

endef
```

All these double dollars are there because `$(eval ...)` will expand variables -- that's desired for `$(T)` and `$(P)` but not for all the other ones, so they are protected with an extra dollar. I'm just quoting the part doing the magic for deciding which files to compile here. If you consider doing something like this, [see the full example](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake/blob/master/mk/bin.mk)